# Error while exporting android source code in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have done a unity project and i need to export it as Android source code. 
But I am getting the following error.

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:187 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

**What I have done from my side,**

- Changed the folder exporting location of the project
- Deleted the Tools folder from Android SDK and re-downloaded the tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip folder and extracted in the SDK path
- Uninstalled Unity and installed latest version
- Re-imported all the Assets files
- Downloaded the latest JDK version and set it in the path

*Any headsup on how to fix this issue would be really helpful. Thanks!*

Comment: might be helpful https://answers.unity.com/questions/1380921/build-failed-with-errors-at-unityeditorbuildplayer.html

Comment: Hi @Redman , I have tried all the steps in the above mentioned link. Its not working for me!

Comment: When you get error, first thing to do is post the software version. Second thing is to post the error message.  You haven't done those two so far. Note that the thing you posted is not an error. Unity usually post 3 error logs on different line in the Console tab after the message in your question. Build the project again then copy each error and post them in your question with your Unity version